# Application invoking using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can we invoke a application from one android in another android device using bluetooth.
If so what is the procedure ???

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot invoke a application from one android to another unless until the both the app use the bluetooth permission and configured.