# How to call bluetooth application using application i am developing?

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application invoking using bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886633/application-invoking-using-bluetooth)

I want to call bluetooth application to send files using my application....
how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886633/application-invoking-using-bluetooth)